# Is there a reason to target id of div inside body instead of just body

Tags: html, css

This code is from the book "Learning Web Design A Beginner’s Guide to HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Web Graphics". So I'm wondering

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>…</header>
        <main>…</main>
        <aside>…</aside>
        <footer>…</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

is there a good reason to use

```
#container {
display: grid;
}
```

instead of

```
body {
display: grid;
}
```

Comment: well. it depends on what you want. To have a grid with container as wrapper or to have a grid with body as wrapper . There are 2 different situations with 2 different results and behaviors . You cannot compare them.

Comment: Yes there is, if you select the body, it will apply your styling to the full body of your page. Whereas if you only select the container, it will apply only to the container. If you want to give a background to only the container you can't put the code in your body. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These don't directly compare. The difference is too big.
From my experience i rarily apply styling to the body element. Also i rarily call html attributes directly (body {}) because this will apply styling globally on every page.

**Firstly**

What I usually do is apply a bodyclass to affect elements on the page but that dont add styling to the body itself. As a random example:

```
<body class="about-page">
   <h1>This is about</h1>
</body>
```

then in Css you could say

```
body.about-page h1 {
   color: #f55d42;
}
```

This will make it so that only on the about page you can change the color of the h1 header tag.

**Secondly**

In your exact usecase I would suggest using the div that has the 'container' **class** instead of **id**. This is because in larger websites or webapps you probably reuse the class 'container' more often and an id may only occur once in your document.

The reason you don't apply it to the body is because this would make the entire html dedicated to being a container. Even if that's the thing you want to do I would still recommend against it for future proofing.

**Lastly**

I see you did the following:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>…</header>
        <main>…</main>
        <aside>…</aside>
        <footer>…</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would suggest this instead

```
<body>
        <header><div class="container"></div></header>
        <main><div class="container"></div></main>
        <aside><div class="container"></div></aside>
        <footer><div class="container"></div></footer>
</body>
```

This is because the header, main, aside and footer elements tend to be used as grouping element rather than an element you would use within a container.

Comment: "Also i rarily call html attributes directly (body {}) because this will apply styling globally on every page." - So will `body > div#container`

Comment: `body.about-page h1 {` this is an anti-pattern.  Just do `.about-page`.

Answer (score 1):

if you put an id or class to your body, then it will affect all inside the body, and when you need to use something outside this class style you cant do it, but when your class to a specific div or other tags, you can add more outside it as you wanted, so it will help to maintain the website in future

Note: "container" is bootstrap class when you use bootstrap in your website try not to put your CSS to bootstrap class it will mess all things